# "declare" keyword not allowed in vue <script setup>

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I want to declare the function `getCookie` in my vue file which is already defined inside the html file in which the vue file will be injected.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
  function getCookie(cookie){
    // do something
  }
</script>
```

If I want to use this function in my vue file I need to use the "declare" keyword.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
declare function getCookie(cookie: string): string;
```

But with the script setup in vue it's not allowed. It shows me "Modifiers cannot appear here". If I don't use `script setup` it works fine.

Comment: "If I want to use this function in my vue file I need to use the "declare" keyword." - do you? What source can you find saying that it's a requirement?

Comment: Well, if I don't use "declare" I will get an error that the function cannot be found. Which makes sense because the function is declared in another file. In some way you need to tell the vue file that the function is already defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I wanted to use the function from the html directly but actually I can just create a separate .js file and write the `get_cookie` function in there. Then I can import the function into both the html and the vue file without the need of `declare`.